# Objective-c self and memory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some debutant questions :

1) When using @propreties and @synthesize, is there a need to do something in the dealloc method ? Or it's not necessary ? ( like release or something else )

2) I have something like :

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *model; // On prend une copie pour le setter
@property (getter=getDistance, nonatomic) float odometer;

// constructeur doit toujours commencer par init
-(id)initWithModel:(NSString *)newModel {

    if(self = [super init]) {
        _model = [newModel copy];
        _odometer = 10.0;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Can I do something like :

```
self.model = [newModel copy];
self.odometer = 10.0;
```

What are the difference here ?

3) Why , for an NSString*, we use copy property ?

```
 @property(**copy**) && _variable = [newVariable **copy**] ..
```

4) For a simple application ( non multi-thread ), can we use the nonatomic for best performance ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you have already set the model property to be of type "copy", you don't need to do [newModel copy]. You can directly just do self.mode = newModel. You don't "have to" "copy" NSString. You just do it because normally you wan't a copy of a string which doesn't change in the program. It's really up to how the program is expected to work for you to choose copy of retain for NSString. You should read Apple's memory management guide, because it explains all this really well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, for `retain` and `copy` properties, the backing variable must be released or the property must be set to `nil` in `-dealloc`, unless you are using ARC.
2. You can, but the official recommendation is not to use accessors in `-init` methods. The difference is that your version sets the backing variable directly, bypassing any side effects (including memory management!) of the accessors you have `@synthesize`d. I should point out, however, that if you are not using ARC, `self.model = [newModel copy];` leaks memory. Replace it with `self.model = [[newModel copy] autorelease];` if you are not using ARC. This is a perfect example of the difference between the two: `_model = [newModel copy];` doesn't leak.
3. `NSString` has a mutable subclass, so you don't want to `retain` a string passed to you, only to find it has mutated later, unbeknownst to you! Instead, make a copy for yourself so that you're sure it won't be messed with by outside objects.
4. Absolutely. Much more than `atomic` is needed for thread safety, anyway.

Comment: Like I said, I'm beginning to objective-c --> a) ARC means ? How can I know if I'm using it ?

Comment: ARC is "Automatic Reference Counting", which manages memory for you. I think the surest way to know if you're using it is to try writing `self.model = [[newModel copy] autorelease];` as I said above... if the compiler says "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'", then you're using ARC. :) If it doesn't, you need to read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html